# If $AB$ is antisymmetric, does that mean $BA = AB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$(AB)^t = B^t A^t = -AB$

I can't come up with any counterexamples.

Comment: think of some $2\times 2$ matrix that is antisymmetric, then write the matrix as a product and chances are you'll have something that won't commute or you won't be able to multiply them in the first place

Comment: @AlvinLepik I tried that with $A = \left(\matrix{a &b\\ -b &a}\right)$ and $B = \left(\matrix{b &a\\ -a &b}\right)$, both antisymmetric and their product is antisymmetric as well, what's more, turns out they are commutative. Any example that still remains in the 2x2 order?

Comment: do you mean the matrices $A$ and $B$ also have to be antisymmetric?

Comment: No, it just so happened to be that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are free, then no. Consider the following.
$$T = \left (\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right ) $$
$T$ is antisymmetric. Now notice that
$$ \left (\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right )\left (\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right ) = T$$
but the terms don't commute, see that already by computing the top left entry.

Comment: Thanks. Any tips on how to come up with the factors of a matrix product like you did without guesswork?

Comment: @daedsidog pick one of the terms such that it's not the identity and is relatively easy to compute with and let the other term be free. In the example I gave, I let the right term be free and I picked left term to my liking. There is still guesswork involved a bit, but it's less arbitrary since you will obtain a system of equations.